# Динамическое меню на YII2

Tags: php, yii2

Доброго всем времени суток.

Вопрос: вот, например, пользователь из админки создает новый пункт меню, в меню прописывается роут. Возможно но ли в YII2 создать такое правило для роутинга, чтобы динамически обрабатывать такой, новый фактически запрос, ведь ни контроллера ни экшена нет. Или перенаправить на дефолтное правило? Возможно ли такое в YII2?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно возможно, пишите роутинг правило с регулярным вырежением. В вашем случае через слэш будет идти обыкновенное значение переменной с типом строка, которое вы передадите в контролллер. Можете использовать их в роутере или передавать в какой-то определённый контроллер/метод в котором вы уже будете решать что показывать в зависимости от переданных аргументов в роутере.

Например:

```
'rules' => [

    [....],

    'page/<name:\w+>' => 'page/index',

    [....]

],
```

В контроллер PageController в метод actionIndex будет передана переменная $name которае будет содержать значение.

> Шаблон правила используется для поиска соответствия с частью URL,
>   определяющей путь. Например, в URL sute.ru/page/about/ путь определяет
>   часть page/about (начальный и конечный слеши игнорируются),
>   соответствующая регулярному выражению page/(\w+).

Comment: А можно небольшой пример с правилом, вас попросить?

Comment: Добавил пример. Информация взята с русскоязычной документации и изменена под вашу ситуацию https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/runtime-routing/#url-rules